# XDomainRequest not giving response while status is 200

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, response, xdomainrequest

XDomainRequest not giving response while status is 200

```
var httpRequest = new XDomainRequest();
httpRequest.open('POST', url, true);
httpRequest.send(xmlDocument);
alert(httpRequest.responseText);
return httpRequest;
```

it is giving response text null. plz guide me where i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing:

```
var httpRequest = new XDomainRequest();
httpRequest.onload=function() {
    alert(httpRequest.responseText);
}
httpRequest.open('POST', url, true);
httpRequest.send(xmlDocument);
```

Comment: It showing me error if apply this.    
    httpRequest.onerror = function() {
        alert("Error!");
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
     };

Comment: does your server return proper "text/xml" content header type for the response being returned if its XML data..?

Comment: and is your service sending a Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP response header with value *, or the exact origin of the calling page...?

Comment: that i am trying that how to send Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP response header

Comment: i dont know java or jsp, but it seems these might help on setting headers:: http://restlet-discuss.1400322.n2.nabble.com/How-to-set-response-header-td7270489.html and http://padcom13.blogspot.com/2011/09/cors-filter-for-java-applications.html

Comment: can we do it no script side or may i change the response header for content type xml